# Problema Flutter en VS Code

Tags: flutter, vscode, depuración

Intento ejecutar la paleta de comandos(Ctrl+Shit+P), para seleccionar un dispositivo y luego correr mi aplicación. Pero ahora ya no me aparece la opción:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero también crear un nuevo proyecto, ahora tengo este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al correr Flutter Doctor aparece todo bien con VSCode:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si intentas directo desde el terminal, ¿da algun error?

```
flutter run
```

o si quieres dentro de un dispositvo especifico puedes buscarlo con

```
flutter devices
```

y ejecutar con

```
flutter run -d <deviceID>
```